# How to allow/call multiple post types in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a newbie in coding. Can you help me this code that I got from jetpack.

```
function allow_my_post_types($allowed_post_types) {
$allowed_post_types[] = ‘wpdmpro’;

return $allowed_post_types;

}
add_filter( ‘rest_api_allowed_post_types’, ‘allow_my_post_types’ );
```

that code above was working perfectly. I allowed 'wpdmpro'

I want to call multiple post types. I want to include 'dwqa-question' and 'topic'.  Please help me if I got wrong with the code that I just created because its not working after added those two post types.

```
function allow_my_post_types($allowed_post_types) {
$allowed_post_types[] = ‘wpdmpro’,’topic’,’dwqa-question’;
return $allowed_post_types;
}
add_filter( ‘rest_api_allowed_post_types’, ‘allow_my_post_types’ );
```

thank you so much for those who can help. I am just learning by myself. Thanks.

Comment: That's PHP code, not jQuery - tags adjusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the values one by one to the array like this:

```
$allowed_post_types[] = ‘wpdmpro’; 
$allowed_post_types[] = ’topic’;
$allowed_post_types[] = ’dwqa-question’;
```

Or you may find some useful solution here:
[PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function allow_my_post_types($allowed_post_types) {
  array_push($allowed_post_types,'wpdmpro','topic','dwqa-question');
  return $allowed_post_types;
}
add_filter( ‘rest_api_allowed_post_types’, ‘allow_my_post_types’ );
```